# Why a subclass in a different package is unable to access the protected fields of its superclass in another package through superclass instance?

Tags: java, package, access-modifiers

**protected** fields of a class are accessible from a subclass in a different package, then why the code shows "The field A.x is not visible?"

```
// A.java
package pack;

public class A {
    protected int x;

    public A() {}

    public A(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void showx() {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

```
// B.java
package pack2;
import pack.*;

public class B extends A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A(5);
        System.out.println(a.x); // The field A.x is not visible
        a.showx(); // 5
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you doing `A a = new A(5);` if `B` extends `A`?  Simply `System.out.println(x);`

Answer (score 2):

You are answering your own question.

> "Protected fields of a class are accessible from a `subclass` in a different package;

In your case `B is the subclass of A`.You can access `x` via

```
B b = new B(); 
System.out.println(b.x);
```

Otherwise it will behave like a `private` access modifier;

Comment: Not exactly like a `private` modifier. Other classes (that are not subclasses) in the same package could also access the `protected` field. This isn't true in all languages, but it's true in Java.

Comment: Thanks for the info . Honestly, I find `protected` kinda peculiar in java :(  .